# Do people on Steam see my non-steam games?

Tags: steam

I have been adding some friends in Steam and I'm thinking if they only see Steam installed games.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add a non-Steam game to your games list and launch it, your friends will see the usual "toast" message, but the text will read *"LT_Spaghetti is now playing non-Steam game: Progress Quest II"*. The name of the game in the Friends list is labeled as "non-Steam" in a similar fashion (although I forget the exact wording right now).

[This question has some additional details about non-Steam games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9616/is-there-any-point-in-adding-a-non-steam-game-to-steam?rq=1).

Comment: You can also rename the executable/shortcut before adding it to steam, and Steam will use that name. This can be used for hilarious effects.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I guess it's really cool for having Steam interface in-game.

Comment: @Robotnik "Robotnik is now playing non-Steam game: Your mom" ?

Comment: @Lyrion - How did you guess? :P

Comment: @Robotnik I'm thinking when people find out they can set the name, they always go for Your mom first ;)

Comment: @Lyrion - Good deductive reasoning :P. I also have Starcraft 2 set to [Crab Nicholson's Extreme Sleepover](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/crab-nicholson)

Comment: @Robotnik Hehe, good choice :p