# Non Steam game on another computer

Tags: steam

I have added a non Steam game to Steam on one of my computers. Is there any way that I can download it to another computer?

Answer (score 8):

No. Non-Steam games are exactly that; games that have nothing to do with Steam, but that it allows you to place a shortcut to in your library. Since the game is not on Steam, you cannot use Steam to download it on another computer.

Comment: What are non-steam games used for anyway? I mean, besides opening up the SteamUI every now and then.

Comment: @user1337 I believe they get tracking stats and show up to your Steam friends.

Comment: The only stat that is tracked is maybe play time. And yeah, basically, you get to launch it from the same menu in Steam you launch all your other games from, you get the Steam Overlay over it (if possible; it can be buggy sometimes, but usually works), and your Steam friends can see that you're playing it.

Comment: @user1337 - You may find the answers to this question helpful: [Is there any point in adding a non-Steam game to Steam?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/9616/is-there-any-point-in-adding-a-non-steam-game-to-steam?rq=1)