# How to remove all non-steam games from games library

Tags: steam

Anyone have any ideas on how best to automatically and en-mass delete all my non-steam game links from my games menu?

Comment: So, you don't want to have quick access to [Hello Kitty: Island Adventure](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1176/steam-says-friend-is-playing-hello-kitty)?

Comment: Since you can't seem to multi-select entries in the games window, I'm guessing no.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe that simply deleting the shortcuts file, which is `<steam installation dir>/config/shortcuts.vdf`, should do it, but I haven't tried it myself so I suggest backing it up first. I don't believe it should do any harm in any case.

Another surefire way is to remove Steam and re-install it, but even if you back up all the game data locally first and then reload it, the whole process will take longer than just removing all the links one by one.

Comment: Renamed it to .bak - cheers

Comment: The path seems to have moved to C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\userdata\########\config

Answer (score 3):

you can choose all the non-steam games by using CTRL and clicking. makes it shorter.